# Setting up a click listener for an infoWindow in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic3

Ok, the case is I'm working in Ionic 3 (which works with Angular 4), and I'm using google maps. Everything is fine to this point, except because I can't set up a click event listener for the `infoWindow` object.

I wanna execute some code when the user clicks in the `infoWindow`. Already tried the following:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'click', function(){
    console.log("click");
    this.openPlace(place.id);
});
```

Also tried putting in a div with an id, which I later use with `getDocumentById()`, and then adding an event listener to that div. Didn't work either. Same trying to put an `onclick` event in that div, and calling to an Angular function. Nothing works.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining `infowindow`?

Comment: let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: content
                    });

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow

InfoWindow object does not broadcast a click event.

This example is from Google's documentation:

```
function initMap() {
  var originalMapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: originalMapCenter
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Change the zoom level',
    position: originalMapCenter
  });
  infowindow.open(map);

  map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    infowindow.setContent('Zoom: ' + map.getZoom());
  });
}
```

Notice how they are not adding listeners directly to the InfoWindow, but to the map. I can't find a single working example of a click listener bound directly to an InfoWindow.

Comment: Hm, so we're in the same point. I will try to see if I can find a solution for this.